# Java - Reading from a file and splitting it into multiple strings

Tags: java, string, file, file-manipulation

I'm looking to read a .txt file and then split it into multiple strings, but excluding some lines.

Example of a file that I would want to split:

```
10:
String One
20:
String Two
```

And so on. I would like all of the numbers and the colon to be ignored and then save the string below it, but stopping at the next number.

I know this is very specific and I've tried to do it myself but I've had no luck. If I can't do it this way, I do have a work around but it will end up with me having a ton of .txt files which isn't very nice.

Comment: What have you done? Which is the problem you are facing that you cannot solve?

Comment: Please show what you've tried so we can start from there instead of starting from scratch.

Comment: Please specify a question, so we can answer.

Comment: Question: How can I do this? I've gotten it to read the file and exclude "//" "[END]" and that's it. I don't know much about file manipulation, I'm trying to learn.

Comment: if you sure the number and the colon appear always on alternate lines,then trying reading linewise and ignore alternate lines..

Answer (score 1):

Why use Java, when sed is perfectly good for this?

```
1,/^10:/d
/^20:/q
```

This removes all lines between the first line and the line starting with `10:`, prints lines after it, and quits when it sees a line starting with `20:`.

Or, if you want to remove all the lines that have a number followed by a colon, you can use this:

```
/^[[:digit:]]\{1,\}:$/d
```

This removes all lines that contain 1 or more digits, then a colon, and nothing else.

Comment: I'll need you to explain that a bit more.. sed?

Comment: Please Google for "sed". All the top hits will tell you everything necessary.

Comment: while `sed` might be an appropriate tool, I think his numbers will be 10, 20, 30, 40 and so on...

Comment: @jlordo Updated my answer to address that case.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

```
Scanner file = new Scanner(new File("file.txt"));
file.useDelimiter("\n?\\d+:\n");

while (file.hasNext())
    System.out.println(file.next());
```

```
String One
String Two
```